# Why is this button placed here, not on the right side?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I'm doing Derek Banas' Android Development Tutorial 11 and I just wanted to move the save button to the right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    ...

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/save_button" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Here's how it looks like:

[image: add_new_contact.xml]

I expected this button to be on the right side, **why** does it stop awkwardly in the middle of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button` is where you would expect it to be: on the right of the first column of that Row. If you set the `layout_gravity` of the Table to be `"right"`, then the first column will push to the right in the absence of a second column, and you will get the desired effect.

A more systematic approach is to put a View (with no content) just before the "Button", *ie.* filling the first column of that view with nothing intentionally.

I think you can also add `android:layout_span="2"` *to the `Button`* to also achieved your desired effect.

Comment: Ah, so if previous table rows have two elements (columns), the next row will also have two columns, even if in my code I define only one, right?

Comment: This answers my question, thanks! I didn't realize that the amount of the columns is changed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="right">

    <View   android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save_button"
            android:onClick="addNewContact"/>

</TableRow>
```

Something has to go in the first cell of the row. For example, you can generate an empty view like this to achieve that or use one of these attributes in the `<Button>` tag.

`android:layout_column` - *The index of the column in which this child should be.*

`android:layout_span` - *Defines how many columns this child should span.*

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your row is not spanning the two columns (though it's strange that the edge of the button overlaps the start of the textfields), try adding `android:layout_span=2` to the Button's TableRow.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, `android:layout_span="2"` added to the TableRow yielded "Invalid layout param in a TableLayout: layout_span".

However, I solved the whole thing by adding `android:gravity="right"` to the TableRow. I still don't know why it's placed so oddly without adding any code, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:layout_gravity="right"`

Comment: Thanks, but I solved the position problem already. My question is more about _why_ the button is placed specifically in this place.